create_model in Pydantic v1 doesn't populate __fields__ attribute
I am using Pydantic v1 in a Langchain implementation of Custom Tools. When I staticly define a Pydantic class it will populate the __fields__ attribute of my class with metadata about the fields -- which is needed by Langchain.
My use case requires that I create Pydantic classes at runtime based on the user's context. I have tried creating Pydantic classes using Python's type function and Pydantic's create_model function. Neither of these approaches populates __fields__
Can anyone fill me in on how to populate __fields__ when creating a Pydantic class dynamicly?
The following code block summarizes what I am expecting vs the actual result.
from enum import Enum

from langchain.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, create_model


class SpecialtyEnumStatic (str, Enum):
    psychiatry = "SPECIALTY:Psychiatry"
    sports_medicine_internal_medicine = "SPECIALTY:Sports Medicine (Internal Medicine)"


class ProviderSearchInputStatic(BaseModel):
    specialty: SpecialtyEnumStatic


print(ProviderSearchInputStatic.__fields__)
# {'specialty': ModelField(name='specialty', type=SpecialtyEnumStatic, required=True)}

specialties = {
    'psychiatry': 'SPECIALTY:Psychiatry',
    'sports-medicine (Internal Medicine)': 'SPECIALTY:Sports Medicine (Internal Medicine)'
}

SpecialtyEnumDynamic = Enum('SpecialtyEnumDynamic', specialties)

ProviderSearchInputDynamic = create_model(
    'ProviderSearchInputDynamic',
    specialty=SpecialtyEnumDynamic,
    __base__=BaseModel
)

print(ProviderSearchInputDynamic.__fields__)
# {}


Just passing a type is not a correct format to define a field. From the docstring of create_model:

fields of the model (or extra fields if a base is supplied) in the format <name>=(<type>, <default default>) or <name>=<default value>, e.g. foobar=(str, ...) or foobar=123, or, for complex use-cases, in the format <name>=<Field> or <name>=(<type>, <FieldInfo>), e.g. foo=Field(datetime, default_factory=datetime.utcnow, alias='bar') or foo=(str, FieldInfo(title='Foo'))

So the correct way would be to pass a tuple (SpecialtyEnumDynamic, ...):
from enum import Enum
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, create_model

specialties = {
    'psychiatry': 'SPECIALTY:Psychiatry',
    'sports-medicine (Internal Medicine)': 'SPECIALTY:Sports Medicine (Internal Medicine)'
}

SpecialtyEnumDynamic = Enum('SpecialtyEnumDynamic', specialties)

ProviderSearchInputDynamic = create_model(
    'ProviderSearchInputDynamic',
    specialty=(SpecialtyEnumDynamic, ...),
)

print(ProviderSearchInputDynamic.__fields__)
# {'specialty': ModelField(name='specialty', type=SpecialtyEnumDynamic, required=True)}

